# Count number of rows in a CSV file with PHP in a particular column

Tags: php, csv

I've got my php working to count the number of rows in the full csv document, but trying to get a number of rows that have data in them in a particular column. Is this possible with PHP?

```
$fp = file('test.csv');
echo count($fp);
```

Comment: It's possible! How are you counting rows? Please edit your post to include code snippets that are appropriate.

Comment: yes I tried counting columns and other approaches but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fgetcsv` function and check in every row the data.

For example if you want to check how many rows have data in the second column, run that.

```
$data_found = 0;
$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle))
{
  if ($data[1] != '')
  {
    // check the data specifically in the second column
    $data_found ++;
  }
}
echo 'Rows with data in the second column:'.$data_found;
```